# Iterate through table and save items in structure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iteration

Alright, so I have this kind of strucure:

```
Structure wspArtikel
    Dim gID As Guid()
    Dim sText As String
    ... more fields like this
End Structure
```

And I also have a HTML-Table with the columns `ID` and `Text`; And an additional column containing a checkbox.
Now I want to iterate (on a `button.Click-Event`) through all the items in the table where the checkbox is checked and save those to my structure.

What I tried:

```
Dim wstruc As New wspArtikel
For Each gRow As GridViewRow In gvArtikel.Rows
    Dim chkArtikel As CheckBox = DirectCast(gRow.FindControl("checkbox"), CheckBox)
    If chkArtikel.Checked Then
        wstruc.gID = New Guid(DirectCast(gRow.FindControl("gID"), HiddenField).Value)
    End If
Next
```

Which works fine if only one item is selected.
As you may already see, if there are two items selected, then it will override the first and only one item will be held in my structure.

How can I collect all the data for each checked item in my structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of using Structs. It is sometimes easier to use another structure like DataTable.

Hint:

To save different occurrences of a struct, you need to use a LIST structure (or some variant of it). Below is an example of using a list of structs. Each item in the list can be accessed by an index. Below I demonstrate adding 1 item (1 occurence of a struct to the list):

```
 Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports System.Text

    Namespace ConsoleApplication1021
        Class Program

            Private Structure wspArtikel
                Public gID As Guid()
                Public sText As String
                '... more fields like this
            End Structure

            Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())

                'Define list 
                Dim structList As New List(Of wspArtikel)()

                'Create list object
                Dim artListVar = New wspArtikel()

                'Define array of 2 items - This is an example, you need to set the correct value
                artListVar.gID = New Guid(1) {}

                'Assign value to array of 1st occurrence in the list
                artListVar.gID(0) = Guid.NewGuid()
                artListVar.gID(1) = Guid.NewGuid()


                'Assign value to string in 1st occurrence in the list
                artListVar.sText = "String-0"

                structList.Add(artListVar)

                      'Display items in list
                       For Each itm As var In structList
                            Console.WriteLine((artListVar.gID(0).ToString() & " ") + artListVar.sText)
                       Next

                Console.WriteLine("Done")
            End Sub
        End Class
    End Namespace
```

Comment: What can I do if I don't know the amount of items in the array (see  `artListVar.gID = New Guid(1) {}`)?

Comment: Maybe you can assume a maximum and use ReDim with Preserve option as in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx before you add to the list.

Comment: is there a way to make the array "dynamic" (since I don't know the amount of checked items beforehand). Ir would it be the best way to iterate through the table once to get the amount of checked items and then creating the array with said amount?

Comment: Knowing the items in advance is probably the best way (most clean) in my opinion.

Comment: Just one more question: Is there a way to loop through the list? Something like `For Each item in structList.Items`

Comment: Where is `var` coming from in `For Each itm As var In structList`?

Comment: itm is an iterator that works with foreach and var is its type.

Comment: I get that, but VS is telling me that the type `var` is not defined.

Comment: I see, I don't have a VB.NET compiler, sorry about that, you may use the specific type instead which is wspArtikel.

Comment: Alright, I think I'll be able to do that :). Thanks for your support!